# Why AngularJS multi-level accordion collapses on data update?

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I needed an AngularJS based multi-level accordion to bind a tree data structure from the back end and I came across this one https://github.com/LukaszWatroba/v-accordion.

It worked pretty well, except it fully collapses (closes any expanded sub accordions) every time data are updated in the controller. I have a timer in the controller that calls the back end to pool data at certain time intervals (e.g., every 3 minutes). I don't know if this is the accordion's built-in behavior or not, but if yes, how this could be fixed?

Any suggestions / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

I reached out to Łukasz Wątroba, the author of this plugin, and with his kind help I was able to resolve this task. Would like to share his feedback in case anybody has a similar goal.

**Solution:**
To your JSON data structure you would need to add two more properties, 
1) the "id" of the pane and
2) the state of the pane "isExpanded" - true/false

These two properties are specifically designed for the front end, to maintain the expand-collapse state of any pane you might have interacted with.

```
  [
    {
      id: 'pane-1b',
      isExpanded: true,
      .................
      all your initial properies...
      .....................
    },
    {
      id: 'pane-2b'',
      isExpanded: false
      .................
      all your initial properies
      .....................
    },
    {
      id: 'pane-3b,',
      isExpanded: false
      .................
      all your initial properies
      .....................

      subpanes: [
        {
          id: 'subpane-1b',
          isExpanded: false
          .................
          all your initial properies
          .....................
        },
        {
          id: 'subpane-2b',
          isExpanded: false
          .................
          all your initial properies
          .....................
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Your HTML would have the following structure, where "panes" is your JSON data.

```
<v-pane id="pane.id" ng-repeat="pane in panes" expanded="pane.isExpanded">
    .................
     <!--For multi level HTML you would have a nested ng-repeat-->

     <v-pane id="subpane.id"  ng-repeat="subpane in pane.subpanes"    expanded="subpane.isExpanded">
     </v-pane>
    .............
</v-pane>
```